# Transform data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a questionnaire with an open-ended question like "Please name up to ten animals", which gives me the following data frame (where each letter stands for an animal):

```
nrow <- 1000
list <- vector("list", nrow)

for(i in 1:nrow){
  na <- rep(NA, sample(1:10, 1))
  list[[i]] <- sample(c(letters, na), 10, replace=FALSE)
}

df <- data.frame()
df <- rbind(df, do.call(rbind, list))

head(df)
# V1   V2 V3 V4   V5 V6   V7 V8 V9  V10
# 1  r <NA>  a  j    w  e    i  h  u    z
# 2  t    o  e  x    d  v <NA>  z  n    c
# 3  f    y  e  s    n  c    z  i  u    k
# 4  y <NA>  v  j    h  z    p  i  c    q
# 5  w    s  v  f <NA>  c    g  b  x    e
# 6  p <NA>  a  h    v  x    k  z  o <NA>
```

How can I transform this data frame to look like the following data frame? Remember that I don't actually know the column names.

```
 r <- 1000
 c <- length(letters)
 t1 <- matrix(rbinom(r*c,1,0.5),r,c)
 colnames(t1) <- letters
 head(t1)
 #      a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
 # [1,] 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0
 # [2,] 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1
 # [3,] 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
 # [4,] 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0
 # [5,] 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
 # [6,] 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `mtabulate` from the "qdapTools" package:

```
library(qdapTools)
head(mtabulate(as.data.frame(t(df))))
#   c d i l m o r v x y a f s t k p u b h j n q e g w z
# 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 3 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 4 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
# 5 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0
# 6 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

---

There are, of course, many other options.

For example, `cSplit_e` from my "splitstackshape" package (with the downside that inefficiently, you need to paste the values together first before you can split them):

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
```

As ones and zeroes:

```
df %>%
  mutate(combined = apply(., 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ","))) %>%
  cSplit_e("combined", ",", mode = "binary", type = "character", fill = 0) %>%
  select(starts_with("combined_")) %>%
  head
#   combined_a combined_b combined_c combined_d combined_e combined_f combined_g combined_h combined_i
# 1          0          0          1          1          0          0          0          0          1
# 2          1          0          0          1          0          1          0          0          0
# 3          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          1
# 4          0          1          1          0          0          0          0          1          1
# 5          0          1          0          1          0          0          0          1          0
# 6          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
#   combined_j combined_k combined_l combined_m combined_n combined_o combined_p combined_q combined_r
# 1          0          0          1          1          0          1          0          0          1
# 2          0          0          0          1          0          0          0          0          0
# 3          0          1          0          0          0          0          1          0          1
# 4          1          0          1          0          1          0          0          0          0
# 5          0          1          0          0          1          0          1          1          1
# 6          1          1          0          1          0          0          0          1          0
#   combined_s combined_t combined_u combined_v combined_w combined_x combined_y combined_z
# 1          0          0          0          1          0          1          1          0
# 2          1          1          0          0          0          0          0          0
# 3          0          1          1          0          0          1          1          0
# 4          0          0          1          0          0          0          1          0
# 5          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0
# 6          1          1          1          0          0          0          0          0
```

As the original values:

```
df %>%
  mutate(combined = apply(., 1, function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ","))) %>%
  cSplit_e("combined", ",", mode = "value", type = "character", fill = "") %>%
  select(starts_with("combined_")) %>%
  head
#   combined_a combined_b combined_c combined_d combined_e combined_f combined_g combined_h combined_i
# 1                                c          d                                                      i
# 2          a                                d                     f                                 
# 3          a                                                                                       i
# 4                     b          c                                                      h          i
# 5                     b                     d                                           h           
# 6                     b                                                                             
#   combined_j combined_k combined_l combined_m combined_n combined_o combined_p combined_q combined_r
# 1                                l          m                     o                                r
# 2                                           m                                                       
# 3                     k                                                      p                     r
# 4          j                     l                     n                                            
# 5                     k                                n                     p          q          r
# 6          j          k                     m                                           q           
#   combined_s combined_t combined_u combined_v combined_w combined_x combined_y combined_z
# 1                                           v                     x          y           
# 2          s          t                                                                  
# 3                     t          u                                x          y           
# 4                                u                                           y           
# 5          s                                                                             
# 6          s          t          u
```

Alternatively, you can use "reshape2":

```
library(reshape2)

## The values
dcast(melt(as.matrix(df), na.rm = TRUE), 
      Var1 ~ value, value.var = "value")

## ones and zeroes
dcast(melt(as.matrix(df), na.rm = TRUE), 
      Var1 ~ value, value.var = "value", fun.aggregate = length)
```

Comment: Haven't come across the qdapTools package so far, but I can't believe how easy the whole thing turns out to be using dcast from the reshape2 pacakge. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
td <-  data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) as.numeric( unique(unlist(df)) %in% x))))
colnames (td) <- unique(unlist(df))
```

`letters` could be replaced with a vector of animal names `colnames(t1)`.

Comment: I think you need to extract the unique elements of `df`. Then use that at the first argument to `%in%`. Otherwise a good answer.

Comment: @BondedDust that would be better. Will unique(unlist(df)) work? I don't have R on my phone.

Comment: Seems to but needs a `colnames (td) <- unique(unlist(df))` to be dressed properly.

Comment: Thank you, everyone! That was definitely a great help (wouldn't have figured that out).

Comment: @not_a_number would `unique(as.vector(t(df)))` be the right order for the columns?

Comment: @germcd Not sure if I understand. Since these are completely arbitrary values, there is no right order, is there?

Comment: @not_a_number in a comment on the other answer you said the column order was preserved

Comment: @germcd Ah, I see. Forrest did not use ones and zeros, but the original column name and NAs. That would make it possible to reconstruct the order of the animal names for each person. That wasn't part of the problem, but it may be useful at later times.

Comment: @not_a_number Ah right, I see the difference in the answers now.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following using tidyr which could be much faster than other approaches, though I like the approach by @germcd very much.  You may need to tinker with the select, removing NAs as well as a blank space, which may be an artifact of the simulated data you provided:

```
require(tidyr)

##  Add an ID for each record:
df$id <- 1:nrow(df)

out <- (df %>% 
  gather(column, animal, -id) %>% 
  filter(animal != " ") %>% 
  spread(animal, column)
)

head(out)
```

This code gathers the unnamed columns into a long format, removes any empty columns or missing data, and then spreads by the unique values of the animal column.  This also has the potentially desirable property of preserving the column order in which the animals were named.  If it's not desirable then you could easily convert the resulting animal columns to numeric:

```
out_num <- out
out_num[,-1] <- as.numeric((!is.na(out[,-1])))
head(out_num)
```

Comment: That's a nice solution, too (especially since the column order is preserved). Thank you very much!